# toggle between input and change event by passing in boolean property

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a basic textfield that fires the input event whenever the amount of characters change.

A basic example would be this textfield

```
        <v-text-field
          :value="value"
          label="Textfield"
          @input="updateValue"
        ></v-text-field>
```

with this Vue instance

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return {
      value: 'abc',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(){
      this.value = updateValue;
    }
  }
})
```

You can see a demo here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgZWrG?editors=1010

The input event gets fired whenever the user is typing. I want to provide an option (boolean property like 'fireInputOnEachInput') and if this is `false` the textfield should use the `change` instead of `input` event.

A possible solution would be to use an `if` statement

```
<v-text-field
  v-if="fireInputOnEachInput"
  :value="value"
  label="Textfield"
  @input="updateValue"
></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
  v-else
  :value="value"
  label="Textfield"
  @change="updateValue"
></v-text-field>
```

but maybe there is a way to switch between the events only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is direct support for using a dynamic event name. In your template:

```js
<v-text-field
  :value="value"
  label="Textfield"
  @[eventName]="updateValue"
></v-text-field>
```

Then add a computed property:

```js
eventName () {
  return this.fireInputOnEachInput ? 'input' : 'change'
}
```

Note that as HTML attribute names cannot contain spaces it's tricky to write this inline. You can find more on this in [the original RFC](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0003-dynamic-directive-arguments.md).

There are various alternatives, such as this:

```js
<v-text-field
  :value="value"
  label="Textfield"
  v-on="{[fireInputOnEachInput ? 'input' : 'change']: updateValue}"
></v-text-field>
```

In this case the square brackets are just an ES6 computed property name, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), not to be confused with Vue computed properties which are a totally different thing.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on for more on the various forms of `v-on`/`@` syntax.